# How do I size a Shiny app within an R-Markdown document using the Tufte Template?

Tags: templates, shiny, r-markdown, tufte

I am writing a report using R-Markdown and the Tufte Template.  I have embedded Shiny apps within the report.

So far I have tried using "fig.width=" and "width=" in the chunck options to no avail, then tried ",
options = list(height = 600)  " just before the closing parenthesis as suggested by B. Davis [change dimensions of shiny app embedded in r markdown HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531553/change-dimensions-of-shiny-app-embedded-in-r-markdown-html) and again no change.

```
hist_dist <- read.csv("hist_dist2.csv", check.names = FALSE)

inputPanel(

selectInput("dist", label = "Choose an ecosystem to explore historical disturbance regimes:", choices = hist_dist$`Ecosystem`, selected = "Northern Hardwoods Forest" ,  width = '70%')
)

renderPlotly({
        ggplot(filter(hist_dist, Ecosystem == input$dist), aes(x=Disturbance, y=Acres)) +
            geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "darkslategrey") +
            coord_flip() +
            theme(legend.position='none') +
            expand_limits(y=c(0, 60)) +
            theme_bw() + 
            theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "grey", fill=NA, size=1), 
            text = element_text(family = "serif", size = 14), 
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
)

}


)
'''


I am able to change the width if I use other templates (non-Tufte), and are able to control the size of figures, just not Shiny apps.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been through the same situation. Tufte_html has something overwriting width behind the scene.

Here's my solution. Not the best but works. Basically you need to assign id to the plot and then change style from CSS.

Edit
output$my_plotly <- renderPlotly(❴❵)

Add 
plotlyOutput("my_plotly") in the same chunk.

Write styles.css with

`#my_plotly ❴ width: 55% !important❵`

Tufte style uses 55% I believe.